Bookmark Lines Between Two Regex Patterns in Notepad++ Without Including the Patterns Themselves
I have a list, and here is an example snippet:
Newii
27,807,147
Supd
26,518,465
Ns.
26,175,538
Mai
24,930,812
Gas
0623,901,055
TEim
20,213,631
Tes
GrV
18,968,412
Mytyttyst
y
htththt
hyhyh
October 2013
/////////////////////////

I want to bookmark the lines between 18,968,412 and October 2013 without including these lines themselves. The following regex works well for matching the lines:
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$)[\s\S]+?^\h*\S.*(?=\R+/{24})

This regex puts [\s\S]+? between ^\d+(?:,\d+)*$(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$) and ^\h*\S.*(?=\R+/{24}). However, the problem is that it also bookmarks the pattern lines themselves.
Output look like after applying the "bookmark":
18,968,412
Mytyttyst
y
htththt
hyhyh
October 2013

I want to bookmark only the lines between the two patterns. For example, in the above list, the lines that should be bookmarked are:
Mytyttyst
y
htththt
hyhyh

Can anyone help me modify the regex so that it only bookmarks the lines between the patterns without including the pattern lines themselves?
Note that I tried following regex but they didn't work too!
(?<=^\d+(?:,\d+)*$\R)[^\R]*(\R(?!^\d+(?:,\d+)*$|\h*\S.*(?=\R/{24}))[^R]*)*(?=\R^\h*\S.*(?=\R/{24}))
(?<=^\d+(?:,\d+)*$(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$)\R)([\s\S]*?)(?=\R^\h*\S.*(?=\R+/{24}))
(?<=^\d+(?:,\d+)*$(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$)\R)[\s\S]*?(?=\R^\h*\S.*(?=\R+/{24}))
(?<=^\d+(?:,\d+)*$(?=(?:\R(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*)*\R/{3,}$))[\s\S]*?(?=^\h*\S.*(?=\R+/{24}))


What does the output look like after applying the "bookmark"?

@TimBiegeleisen post edited - read again

Are you specifically looking for the integer value 18,968,412, or just the last integer before October 2013?  Is the close of the bookmark the exact value October 2013, or is it any month year combination?

You can use
^\d+(?:,\d+)*\R(?=(?:(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*\R)*/{3,}$)\K(?:(?!^/{3,}$)[\s\S])*?(?=(?!/{3,}$).*\R/{3,}$)

See the regex demo.
Details:

^\d+(?:,\d+)*\R(?=(?:(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*\R)*/{3,}$)  - matches the last comma-separated digit sequences line before /// like line
\K - discards all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
(?:(?!^/{3,}$)[\s\S])*? - zero or more chars as few as possible, each of each is not a starting point of a line that only consists of three or more slashes
(?=(?!/{3,}$).*\R/{3,}$) - a positive lookahead that requires the following patterns to match immediately to the right of the current location:

(?!/{3,}$) - a check that fails the match if there are three or more slashes till the end of the line
.* - a whole line
\R - a line break
/{3,}$  - three or more / chars till the end of the line.



See the NPP demo:


tnq but your regex not working good on some part of my list. see https://regex101.com/r/yFBFBt/1

@PubgMobile What about ^\d+(?:,\d+)*\R(?=(?:(?!\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*\R)*/{3,}$)\K(?:(?!^/{3,}$)[\s\S])*?(?=(?!/{3,}$).*\R/{3,}$)?

yes it worked good - edit your answer plz
